# C# RegEx to find empty cells in pipe delimited file

Tags: c#, regex, regex-greedy

I'm looking for a little guidance with RegEx patterns.

I have a pipe delimited file which I and I want to remove all lines where the fourth cell is blank. Each line can have any number of cells.

My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EpicRemoveBlankPriceRecords
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string line;

            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            System.IO.StreamReader inFile = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test\\test.txt");
            System.IO.StreamWriter outFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test\\test_out.txt");
            while ((line = inFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Match myMatch = Regex.Match(line, @".*\|.*\|.*\|\|.*");
                if (!myMatch.Success)
                {
                    outFile.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }

            inFile.Close();
            outFile.Close();

            //// Suspend the screen.
            //Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. I THINK it's because the RegEx is "greedy" - this matches if there are any blank cells because I haven't explicitly said "catch everything EXCEPT a pipe character". A quick google and I see I can do that using [^\|] in the pattern.

So, if I change the pattern to:

```
 ".*[^\|]\|.*[^\|]\|.*[^\|]\|\|.*"
```

Why doesn't this work either?

Guess I'm a little confused, any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You were too quick for me - I noticed that and edited accordingly. My pattern unfortunately still isn't working.

Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason you need to use regex here? Looks to me like doing something like `string.IsNullOrEmpty(line.Split('|')[2])` would be much easier.

Comment: 3rd item from 1 or from 0? =)

Comment: thanks @Maslow - I edited to fourth for clarification

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken I'm really interested in learning more about regex, but you are correct - a split would be the easiest solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/):

```
^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|\|.*
```

- `^` alone means start of line
- `[^|]` any character except `|`
- `[^|]*` match zero or more non `|` characters
- `+`  may be wrong for your usage but it means at least one and however many more it finds
- `.*` means anything at all and as many of them as it can find.

test data:

- abc|123|234||673
- abc|def||123|456
- abc|123|234|673||ab

Comment: Sorry for the edit. Again though, we catch blank fields later in the file - eg. I catch for      abc|123|234|673||ab||

Comment: Thanks @Maslow. I've accepted this as an answer as it does what I need and has excellent clarification - looks like my mistake was that I don't need to escape the pipe from within the [].

Comment: http://j.mp/1arsY2T - updated link with more test data, and the `+` was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need regex here?

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filename)
           .Where(line => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line.Split('|')[3]));

File.WriteAllLines(outfile, lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

`.*[^\|]` means zero or more wild-cards (`.*`) and one character that isn't a `|` (`[^\|]`).

Also, you need to escape `|` inside `[]`.

And [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) doesn't actually match, it searches, so you need `^` at the start of the regex (which indicates the start of string).

And the trailing `.*` is thus also not required.

You instead want zero or more characters that aren't `|`, like this:

```
"^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|\|"
```

[Test](https://ideone.com/kHbjI4).

**Why `".*\|.*\|.*\|\|.*"` didn't work:**

Apart from the above reasons...

`*` being greedy doesn't really change much (you can make it non-greedy / lazy by doing `.*?`). The problem is that `.` also matches `|` and it backtracks, so `.*` will include as many or as few `|`'s as required for it to match the string (yes, it will try to include more because it's greedy, but this doesn't change whether or not it finds something, only what it finds).

You can hack something together using lazy matching and [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), but it will end up being somewhat more complex and, more importantly, I suppose, C# doesn't support those.

Comment: This seems to still catch if there are blank cells later in the file (example, if the 5th cell is blank it catches for cells 2, 3, 4 and 5)

Comment: @Ekins86 This should work, just add the `^` and `$` to the start and end of the regex.

Comment: @Ekins86 Seems `Match` doesn't match, it searches. Edited my answer a bit.